# How does having an empty stomach affect absorption of compounds?

Tags: physiology, pharmacology, medicine, stomach

From personal experience, compounds such as nicotine, caffeine and alchohol appear to absorb much quicker into the blood on an 'empty' stomach', or after extended periods of fasting. **If this is the case, why would that occur?**

Does time play a significant role in absorption in an average 'healthy' individual? Are there any srudies published on this phenomenon?

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE... have you looked anywhere in particular for the answer to this question? You may want to google drug absorption without or  with food. Different nutrients can affect the rate of gastric emptying (i.e. prolonged gastric emptying with fatty foods), though if you are strictly talking absorption from the stomach that may not matter (or could if you're taking about a highly lipophilic drug). Can you clarify if you are talking specifically about gastric specifically or overall GI absorption? Are you talking about "food compounds" or "drug compounds" or both?